# Naming and Uses for $n$-Orthotope divided into Orthants

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

The object I’m thinking about is an $n$-dimensional Orthotope (generalization of a rectangle), which is sectioned into $2^n$ orthants (generalization of quadrant). A couple of questions…

1. What’s the proper name for this object (if such a name exists)? That will help me find literature about it…
2. Are there any problems where such a structure would be useful?
3. Are there general properties about this object that are known?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dyadic decomposition is often used in analysis

Comment: Thank you for the lead @FShrike! Would you happen to have any particular examples in mind?

Comment: None of them are terribly specific or interesting is the thing, but all are useful. Splitting space into many cubes with edges size $2^{-n}$ is used… in measure theory, to prove little lemmas about the relation between Lebesgue measure and topology; to show every open set is the almost disjoint union of rectangles; to approximate surfaces; in the appendix of Hatcher’s AT, there’s a very unclear proof of a topological lemma that relies heavily on cube decomposition

Comment: The main point is that it lends itself well to *inductive construction*. We can build a set, or function, or neighbourhood - whatever - looking at the cubes of size $1,1/2,1/4,1/8,…$ in succession, and the cubes can be arranged so that their union tends towards a more desired set but where the more desirable set is harder to think about or do things with

Comment: I see. Thank you for writing all of that out!! It’s a little different than the purpose I’ve been thinking about this structure for thus far, but good to know it can be used in these other ways!